# Browser Stuck On Media Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z3mq3mhu/23/) to illustrate the problem which is this:

I have a desktop and mobile menu, the mobile activates at 480px or below, if you open the fiddle, resize window until the hamburger icon appears, click run, click the hamburger and then click any link. The menu collapses as it should.

If you then resize the window back to full width the menu text is missing because the 480px media query has a display:none on the ul element in order for the menu to not be permanently displayed in mobile mode.

Am I missing something here? Should the browser not detect it's back to full width and therefore ignore the media query and revert back to default display:inline for the ul element?

This also happens on smaller devices between portrait and landscape modes which is really my concern.

Any help, is of course, appreciated.

UPDATE

I have a new fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/85nveuLb/1/) which is nearly working correctly, the one issue remaining is on resize back to full width clicking on a link (ul) causes the menu to slide up but this should only happen below 480px.
Again any help would be appreciated.

Thanks to Chandra Shekhar for some script used in this updated fiddle.

```
<nav>
<a class="fa fa-bars"></a>
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
<li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
<li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
<li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

nav {
width:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0;
text-align:center;
z-index:100;
background:grey;
padding:10px 0;
}

nav ul {
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

nav ul li {
display:inline;
padding:0 12px;
}

.fa-bars {
display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
nav ul {
width:100%; 
position:absolute;
top:37px;
display:none;
}

nav ul li { 
display:block;  
border-top:1px solid #868686;
background:grey;
padding:10px;
}

nav ul li a {
padding:12px 18px;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
border-top:none;
}

.fa-bars {
display:inline;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   if ( $(window).width() > 480) {} 
   else {
   $(".fa-bars").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".menu").slideToggle("slow");
  });

  $(document).click(function () {
    $(".menu").slideUp("slow");
  });
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add only below js:

you have already use slidetoggle then not need to slideUp.

See [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z3mq3mhu/24/)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   if ( $(window).width() > 480) {} 
   else {
   $(".fa-bars").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".menu").slideToggle("slow");
  });


}
});
```

Comment: when the menu closes in the mobile mode , stretch the window, links are not available

Comment: Thanks, yes that works but the menu needs to collapse when clicking links as per my original fiddle. Also with your fiddle if you open and close mobile menu without clinking any links then resize to full width the text has still disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

The `slideToggle()` method is creating the issue. As per the jQuery docs the `slideToggle()` method animates the height property of the element.When the `height` reaches `0` after a hiding animation, the `display` style property is set to `none`.

That is the reason the links are not visible.

Give this Fiddle a Try

JS

```
$(document).ready(function (){

  $(".fa-bars").on('click',function(){
    $(".menu").slideToggle("slow");
   });

//
  $(window).resize(function(){
    if($(this).width()>480)
    {
        $(".menu").show();
    }
  });

});
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/z3mq3mhu/27/)

Here I used `window.resize` function just to show you. As of my knowledge there will be no necessity of using that function.

Hope this Helps

Comment: You've nearly got it except the menu needs to collapse when clicking any link as per my original fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   if ( $(window).width() > 480) {} 
   else {
   $(".fa-bars").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".menu").slideToggle("slow");
  });

  $(document).click(function () {
    $(".menu").toggle("slow");
  });
}
});
```

```css
nav {
width:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0;
text-align:center;
z-index:100;
background:grey;
padding:10px 0;
}

nav ul {
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

nav ul li {
display:inline;
padding:0 12px;
}

.fa-bars {
display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
nav ul {
width:100%; 
position:absolute;
top:37px;
display:none;
}

nav ul li { 
display:block; 
border-top:1px solid #868686;
background:grey;
padding:10px;
}

nav ul li a {
padding:12px 18px;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
border-top:none;
}

.fa-bars {
display:inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
<a class="fa fa-bars"></a>
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
<li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
<li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
<li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```